# How could I get html source from enter URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is index : [link](https://gyazo.com/76cb1ffe01e3df8c6289aad6202264b4)

`code .js:`

```
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        //  $('#iframe').outerHTML();
        //  console.log($('#iframe').outerHTML());
    });
});
```

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: You would like get html content using JavaScript from your own page iframe or remotely?

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is old, this answer might be useful for others. It is possible to simply use ajax request to get the html content of a link.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'your-url', success: function(data) { alert(data); } });
```